# Need to read XML files as a stream using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have a dilemma.

I need to read very large XML files from all kinds of sources, so the files are often invalid XML or malformed XML. I still must be able to read the files and extract some info from them. I do need to get tag information, so I need XML parser.

Is it possible to use Beautiful Soup to read the data as a stream instead of the whole file into memory?

I tried to use ElementTree, but I cannot because it chokes on any malformed XML.

If Python is not the best language to use for this project please add your recommendations.

Comment: lxml has a stream api, you can check the documentations here: https://lxml.de/3.6/parsing.html#incremental-event-parsing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beautiful Soup has no streaming API that I know of. You have, however, alternatives.

The classic approach for parsing large XML streams is using an event-oriented parser, namely SAX. In python, `xml.sax.xmlreader`. It will not choke with malformed XML. You can avoid erroneous portions of the file and extract information from the rest.

SAX, however, is low-level and a bit rough around the edges. In the context of python, it feels terrible.

The `xml.etree.cElementTree` implementation, on the other hand, has a much nicer interface, is  pretty fast, and can handle streaming through the `iterparse()` method.

`ElementTree` is superior, if you can find a way to manage the errors.